# How to make Requests module work with Python 3.2?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-requests

I am currently experiencing problems with getting the Requests module to work with Python 3.2 on my Raspberry Pi running Raspian. I have installed Requests and it actually works for Python 2.7. However, when trying to install it for 3.2 it looks like this in the terminal:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo pip-3.2 install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
Downloading requests-2.11.1.tar.gz (485Kb): 485Kb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package requests
warning: no files found matching 'test_requests.py'
Installing collected packages: requests
Running setup.py install for requests
warning: no files found matching 'test_requests.py'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 856
    http_error_msg = u'%s Client Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, reason, self.url)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
```

So it says successfully installed requests, but importing the module in a Python script is not possible. Any help in solving this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Add your python code, please

Comment: He's running `setup.py` for `requests`.  He doesn't have any python code yet...

Comment: I notice in [the faq](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/community/faq/#python-3-support) that python 3 is only "supported" beginning with version 3.3.

Comment: Yeah, it's the first line "import requests" in the Python code causing problems and a similar error message as the one above.

Comment: Can you upgrade to jessie, which seems to have Python 3.4?

Comment: It is simply not supported, why are you using python 3.2 in the first place?